# Code Coverage not showing in Azure Devops after enabling options

Tags: azure-devops

I have service fabric project .net core 2.1 project and have created unite test case. I added the VSTest step after the build step and enabled "Code Coverage Enabled" but I do not see any information related code coverage after the build.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or Private agent?

Comment: We are using Private agent

Comment: You need VS Enterprise installed on the build agent, do you have it?

Comment: I had this same issue but with an Azure-based build agent, and it was due to using the dotnet test task rather than the Visual Studio test task. Switching to VS caused code coverage to pop up as expected.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need the test sdk's running on the agent (VS Pro or Enterprise). You can also use the  Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task for this, as this will install all the necessary tools.
2. You need to publish the test results with a task 'Publish test results' if I am correct.

Comment: So you mean in addition to VS Pro or Enterprise I will need to install test sdk on the private agent ?

Comment: No, if you already have Pro or Enterprise, this shouldn't be needed, only step 2.

Comment: If my agent has VS community and add in Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task then it will show the code coverage.

Comment: No, only if you do step 2 as well